500 server error in Next js. after netlify deploy
Look my Next js project works itself normally in local, however when I added languages in project(next18n) it started to give 500 internal server error in global host. in local host everything is normal. but in localhost I get 500 internal Server Error.
My website url below
https://anco.ac/en
website is opening, layout is opening, but the pages inside that nope.
what can be the problem and how to fix ?
I built my website with netlify, however I can't find logs of netlify there. Overall. this is my code
I18n config below
const path = require('path');
const i18next = require('i18next');
const {initReactI18next} = require('react-i18next');

i18next
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        debug: true,
        resources: {
            ru: {
                common: require('./public/locales/ru/common.json'),
            },
            en: {
                common: require('./public/locales/en/common.json'),
            },
        },
        ns: ['common'],
        defaultNS: 'common',
    });

module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        defaultLocale: 'en',
        locales: ['ru', 'en'],
    },
    localePath: path.resolve('./public/locales'),
    react: {
        useSuspense: false,
    },
};


layout code below.
import Image from "next/image";
import { IMAGES } from "../assets";
import { selectInitData } from "../store/init/selector";
import { init } from "../store/init/actions";
import { BiCart } from "react-icons/bi";
import { FaFacebook, FaInstagram, FaPhoneAlt, FaTelegram } from "react-icons/fa";
import { GiHamburgerMenu } from "react-icons/gi";
import { HiOutlinePaperAirplane } from "react-icons/hi2";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { FaBucket } from "react-icons/fa6";
import Link from "next/link";
import russianFlag from "../public/russiaFlag.png";
import usaFlag from "../public/usaFlag.png";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { MdOutgoingMail } from "react-icons/md";
import { useTranslation } from "next-i18next";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
    const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);
    const selectInitSiteDetails = useSelector(selectInitData);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const router = useRouter();
    const { locale } = router;

    const changeLanguage = (language) => {
        router.push(router.pathname, router.asPath, { locale: language });
    };

    console.log(locale)

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(init());
    }, [dispatch])

    const handleOpenModal = () => {
        setClickCount(clickCount + 1);
        setIsMenuOpen((prev) => !prev)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Link href='/busket'>
                <div className='busket_icon'>
                    <FaBucket className='bucket__icon'/>
                </div>
            </Link>
            <div className="header">
                <Link href='/'>
                    <Image src={IMAGES.logo} width={220} height={100} className="header_logo" alt='jhgfdsdfghj'/>
                </Link>
                <div className="header__text_block">
                    <Link href='/'>
                        <span className="header_text">{t('home')}</span>
                    </Link>
                    <Link href='/collections'>
                        <span className="header_text">{t('collections')}</span>
                    </Link>
                    <Link href='/aboutUs'>
                        <span className="header_text">{t('about_us')}</span>
                    </Link>
                    <Link href='/contact'>
                        <span className="header_text">{t('contact')}</span>
                    </Link>

                    <div className='language__switcher'>

                        <div className={locale === 'en' && 'selected_flag'} onClick={() => changeLanguage('en')}>
                            <Image src={usaFlag} className='flags'
                                   alt='usa flag'/>
                        </div>
                        <div className={locale === 'ru' && 'selected_flag'} onClick={() => changeLanguage('ru')}>
                            <Image src={russianFlag}
                                   className='flags'
                                   alt='russian flag'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <span className="header_text header_ant">|</span>
                    <a href={selectInitSiteDetails.instagram_link} target="_blank">
                        <FaInstagram className="header_icon"/>
                    </a>
                    <a href={selectInitSiteDetails.facebook_link} target="_blank">
                        <FaFacebook className="header_icon"/>
                    </a>
                    <a href={selectInitSiteDetails.tiktok_link} target="_blank">
                        <FaTelegram className="header_icon"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <GiHamburgerMenu className={`header__hamburger_icon`} onClick={handleOpenModal}/>
                <div
                    className={`header__mobile_menu ${isMenuOpen ? 'active-menu' : clickCount > 1 ? 'inactive-menu' : ''}`}>
                    <Link href='/'>
                        <span className="header_text">{t('home')}</span>
                    </Link>
                    <Link href='/collections'>
                        <span className="header_text">{t('collections')}</span>
                    </Link>
                    <Link href='/aboutUs'>
                        <span className="header_text">{t('about_us')}</span>
                    </Link>
                    <Link href='/contact'>
                        <span className="header_text">{t('contact')}</span>
                    </Link>
                    <div className='language__switcher'>
                        <div className={locale === 'en' && 'selected_flag'} onClick={() => changeLanguage('en')}>
                            <Image src={usaFlag} className='flags'
                                   alt='usa flag'/>
                        </div>
                        <div className={locale === 'ru' && 'selected_flag'} onClick={() => changeLanguage('ru')}>
                            <Image src={russianFlag}
                                   className='flags'
                                   alt='russian flag'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <BiCart className="header_icon"/>
                    <div className="header__mobile_network_block">
                        <a href={selectInitSiteDetails.instagram_link} target="_blank">
                            <FaInstagram className="header_icon"/>
                        </a>
                        <a href={selectInitSiteDetails.facebook_link} target="_blank">
                            <FaFacebook className="header_icon"/>
                        </a>
                        <a href={selectInitSiteDetails.tiktok_link} target="_blank">
                            <FaTelegram className="header_icon"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {children}
            <footer>
                <div className="footer">
                    <div className="footer__text_container">
                        <Link href='/'>
                            <span className="footer_title">anco</span>
                        </Link>
                        <Link href='/collections'>
                            <span className="footer_text">{t('collections')}</span>
                        </Link>
                        <Link href='/aboutUs'>
                            <span className="footer_text">{t('about_us')}</span>
                        </Link>
                        <Link href='/blog'>
                            <span className="footer_text">{t('blogs')}</span>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="footer__text_container">
                        <span className="footer_subtitle">contact us</span>
                        <div className="phone_block">
                            <FaPhoneAlt className="footer_icon"/>
                            <span className="phone_number">{selectInitSiteDetails.phone_number_1}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="phone_block">
                            <FaPhoneAlt className="footer_icon"/>
                            <span className="phone_number">{selectInitSiteDetails.phone_number_2}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="phone_block">
                            <MdOutgoingMail className="footer_icon"/>
                            <span className="phone_number">{selectInitSiteDetails.gmail}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="footer__text_container">
                        <span className="footer_subtitle">Subscribe</span>
                        <div className='container__send_email'>
                            <HiOutlinePaperAirplane className='send__email_button'/>
                            <input className='send__email_input' placeholder='Write your Email'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Layout;


